# If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, and $K$ is normal, then $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

$HK$ is the set of all products $hk$ where $h \in H$ and $k \in K$. Quotient groups are the next chapter in my textbook, so please avoid using them.

I figured out inverse-closure: $h^{-1}\in H$, $k^{-1}\in K$,  $h^{-1}k^{-1}\in HK$

$h^{-1}k^{-1} = (kh)^{-1}$

RHS $= (hk^{'}h^{-1}h)^{-1}$  because $k$ is normal and $k = gk^{'}g^{-1}$ for any $g \in G$

RHS $=(hk^{'})^{-1}$ for every $h\in H$ and $k^{'}\in K$ possible.

Operation-closure is giving me trouble. I don't know how to prove every $hkh^{'}k^{'}\in HK$  I suspect this might be a bad place to start.

Comment: What is $k'$ here?

Comment: Hint the First: for arbitrary subgroups $H$ and $K$, $HK$ is a subgroup if and only if $HK=KH$ as sets. Hint the Second: if $K$ is normal, then for each $h\in H$, $hK=Kh$. As to your work: note that $kh$ is not obviously in $HK$: it is a product of something in $K$ by something in $H$, **not** of something in $H$ by something in $K$. You need to show that you can express $(hk)^{-1}=k^{-1}h^{-1}$ as the product of something in $H$ by something in $K$.

Comment: @Arturo  But (hk)^{-1} = k^{-1}h^{-1} is basic to groups and inverses. Why can't it be used?

Comment: @ Bernard $k^{'}$ is any element in $K$ that can be k or not.  Is there a more typical convention for saying that?

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: @JenniferClarke: It’s not that it can’t be used: it’s what you need to show that $(hk)^{-1}$ lies in $HK$, which means you need to show that it can (also) be expressed as the product of something in $H$ by something in $K$, **in that order**. It’s not enough to know it equals $k^{-1}h^{-1}$, because that element is not clearly in $HK$.

Comment: @Shaun "A Book of Abstract Algebra 2nd Edition" by Charles C. Pinter.

Comment: What you write about $k’$ is, if taken literally, wrong. You say “$k=gk’g^{-1}$ for any $g\in G$”. Taken literally, you are saying that no matter what $g$ is, you will have $k=gk’g^{-1}$; so for $g=e$ you have $k=k’$; and then you are saying that for all $g$ $k=gkg^{-1}$, and that means $k$ commutes with every element of $G$. *Clearly* that is not what you mean to say. And also, you should *never* use an element before you say what that element is. $k’$ is not an arbitrary element, it is supposed to be a *specific* element with *specific* properties. What are they?

Comment: @verret No, I'm missing too much of the foundation of why to comprehend what works and what's enough.

Answer (score 0):

Fill in details: for $\;h,h'\in H\;,\;\;k,k'\in K\;$ , we have

$$hkh'k'=\overbrace{h(kh'k^{-1})}^{\in H}\,\overbrace{kk'}^{\in K}\in HK$$

Comment: You’ve got it mixed up... $K$ is the one that is normal.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ah, true. Well, if the OP understood then he can fix it.